# When I search for a feature here, give me a hint about how to access it

Tags: feature-request, search

If I am a new user, and I search for a feature, like "Community Wiki" or "Badges", it is likely I would like to know more about them.

The best place to learn about badges is the badges page, so could there be some sort of UI navigation hint at the top, to say User Profile -> Badges.

[image]

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ no, I don't do freehand :P

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really needed.

If someone seek help with the site features, he/she will click the "help" link on top:

> [image]

Lo and behold! The Help Center got a search of its own:

> [image]

Typing there "community wiki" [leads exactly to the results you expected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=community+wiki):

> [image]

Happy searching! :)